# What is the most direct way of addressing a graphics chip?

Tags: assembly, x86, gpu, intel

My oldish PC has an Intel HD 420 in it.

I was wondering - we can use Assembly code to address the CPU directly, with commands like `mul`, `add` etc.

How can I pass on Assembly calculation commands to a graphics chip such as the Intel HD, or say the "gpu part" of AMD's Ryzen? Is it the same mechanics as for an ARM graphics chip?

(No tags for apu, onboard-graphics, intel-hd, ryzen)

Edit: I understand that OpenCL is the correct approach, and that an on-board chip is as good as any other peripheral hardware (eg printer) as far as communication.
However, out of theoretical curiosity, looking for the simplest Assembly snippet, that does any sort of mundane calculation on an onboard graphics chip like an Intel HD XXX.

Comment: What the gpu runs and how and how to access is chip/board specific, there may be some overlap but assume each are different.  It is separate logic, in no way connected to the main processor so how you use it depends on the design.  The vendor may also not publish those details, so you may have to reverse engineer open source projects.

Comment: No reason to assume intel, amd, arm, etc would be remotely the same much less intel product x vs intel product y.  Pick one, research it, if you hit a dead end, pick another, repeat until you give up or succeed.    The raspberry pi GPU is documented.

Comment: If it's enough to see how a VGA card is accessed, you can search for "VGA" and "assembly" and something should come out. If you really want to see how to use the programmable part of the GPU (i.e. the shaders) then you probably want to first study [the Intel Graphic HD PRM](https://github.com/Igalia/intel-osrc-gfx-prm/tree/master/011_kbl_-_2016-2017). Any low-level code that does that would be just too long and obscure. Note that GPUs have their own assembly (e.g. [NVIDIA PTX](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/parallel-thread-execution/index.html)) if that's what you are looking for.

Answer (score 4):

The GPU is a separate core you can only interact with via MMIO; it's not a coprocessor like x87 originally was (where `fmul` ran on a separate chip).  You can access it the same way the graphics drivers do.

There is no CPU instruction that does stuff on the GPU directly because it's not tightly-coupled *at all*, hence the high latency being a problem for GPGPU.  Sending work to the GPU looks like storing to memory and then passing a pointer to that physical memory to the GPU, e.g. via `mov [mem], rax` or something to the address of one of the GPU's MMIO registers.

For Intel, those are open source if you really want to dive in to Linux DRM (direct rendering manager) and X11 drivers that talk to the GPU after asking the kernel for access.

Comment: Can you give a smallish example of how it's done, some simple vector calculation?

Comment: @Jay: Hell no.  There's a huge baseline of complexity you need just to talk to the GPU *at all*, not matter how simple the problem.  I don't know how to write even a minimal driver for i915 / Intel-HD hardware!  I just know that (like every other modern device), they'll involve MMIO reads and writes like you'd have for a PCIe device, and also involve writing to device (video) memory or having the GPU read system memory.  I think you could make DRM system calls on Linux to request access to those, or else the kernel itself does the real access.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. OpenCL is considered the lowest "reasonable" way to talk to onboard chips then, and for some chips it comes precompiled so you don't know what's going on?

Comment: @Jay: Yes.  Although you can get somewhat fine control over the code that actually runs on the GPU, e.g. I think you can use inline (GPU) asm in an OpenCL kernel.  But getting that GPU code onto the GPU (and doing memory management) is best left to the graphics drivers.  There are open-source 3D drivers for all the major GPUs, though; in the case of NVidia they're reverse engineered so don't support the latest NV chips right away.  I'm not sure if they support OpenCL (I'd guess probably) and they do certainly support shader programs.  So the info is there, it's just too complex to reimplement.

Answer (score 1):

If you need the ISA for Intel HD graphics, [here it is](https://software.intel.com/content/dam/develop/external/us/en/documents/micro-2016-isa-tutorial-698638.pdf). Intel provides the programmer's reference manuals for all their graphics chips [here](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/documentation/hardware-specification-prms). These information can be used to create a graphics driver for Intel HD graphics, which is the most "direct" way of accessing the GPU.

Please note this is for Intel HD graphics as they are the only one who provides ISA documentation for open source driver development as I know.

Best of luck!

Comment: Note that answers on Stack Overflow should be able to stand up on their own without relying just on links.  Please consider adding some examples or details from that reference to the answer so it is useful even if the link goes down.